# Cancel debian package installation inside preinst script

Tags: debian, installation-package

I would like to cancel the installation of a .deb package if a check fails in my preinst script.

My preinst script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Stop if any error
set -e 
assertexists(){
    # $1 File
    if [ -e "$1" ]
    then
        echo "File existence checked for: $1"
    else
        echo "ERROR, file does not exist: $1"
        exit 1
    fi
}
assertexists "$JAVAPATH/bin/java"
```

When i run:

```
dpkg -i my.deb
```

I see the error but the package appears as installed when i run:

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

Is there a way to cancel the installation inside preinst ?

Answer (score 0):

I recall there is some dpkg switch to disable execution of preinst/postinst script ( check with dpkg manpage), however if you already started installation and it broke ( as it sometimes happen ) and you can't get out of error loop, the simplest way is to put

```
exit 0
```

in /var/lib/dpkg/info/PACKAGENAME.postinst ( or preinst respectively )

I believe installation must finish successfully or unsuccessfully ( if 2nd then package must be purged by hand ), so there would be no "official" way of some "cancel, remove_me()" in preinst/postint script. You could put dpkg --purge in the script in some case, but I guess it won't do, due to lock or whatever else, would rather make no sense. Note how apt-get does multiple install/removal - it usually first removes all packages which are to be removed, and then install remaining ones. You can also make

```
echo PACKAGENAME purge | dpkg --set-selections
```

and then

```
apt-get -f dselect-upgrade
```

or

```
apt-get -f install
```

but I think it is not the way it's supposed to work.

You can also do by hand

```
dpkg -i mypackage.deb || dpkg --purge mypackage
```

Generally, dependencies are to provide a way of conditional installation or removal. You might want to create dummy dependance or dependent package, which will fail before or after installation and trigger dependency warning. Such package will then be listed within "autoremove" list.

Comment: Having a package that in it's install or removal script makes its own calls to mess with the package system seems like a horrible idea.

Comment: correct, even if it's possible - according to "where is unix there is a way"